# Printing receipt from additional project freeze application

Tags: c#, process, backgroundworker

I know that there was lot of topic like this one, but i read almost all of them and still don't have answer. So at the begining I'll show code.

After I click in button on my application, I'm opening .exe file with parameters which print receipt:

```
string[] Arguments = { ....... };
            string arg = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Arguments.Length; i++)
            {
                arg += "\"" + Arguments[i] + "\" ";
            }

            string appPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString();


            if (File.Exists(ExecutableFilePath))
            {
                var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = ExecutableFilePath,
                        Arguments = arg,
                        WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath),
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = false,
                    }
                };

                proc.Start();
            }
```

Actually, to be more specific it works like:

Button.Click method:

- check if entered price >= receipt price
- switch pressedButton by name (card, cash, coupon etc) and goto method printReceipt

printReceipt method:

- run method which contains exe declaration etc (like above).

And the printReceipt.exe code:

```
 public PrintReceiptForm(string[] Args)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(PrintReceiptForm_Load);
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted + =new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }



void PrintReceiptForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!worker.IsBusy)
            {
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

- worker.doWork run method1 (load all data from database to list), method2 (load payment method from database to structure), method3 (print receipt which use list from m1, m2).

And I have to say, that doesn't really changed much. What I wanted to achieve, is that, after user click on button, ui will be unfrezzed after 1 second. At this momment when I have 150 products in receiptList, I need to wait 10 second of app freeze, after that 3-5 second till receipt is being printed.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Wasn't really good threads, BackgroundWorkers, Process'es etc..

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how threading helps here?

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong, impossible to guess what.  Don't call ReportProgess too often.

Comment: @EmmadKareem I asked another question about that and someone told me that, best way to do it is create another project and call it as process from main application. Actually my problem is that, when I run process from code, that still does freeze my first application (button is 'pressed' for couple seconds) - and before I create printReceipt project I was pretty sure it will help without freezing UI from mainapp.

Comment: @HansPassant - one simple question. Let's say that I have project with one button, and another with sqldatareader which load 100 000 rows to structure. When I click on button i'd like to run .exe (with reader). Tell me if I'm wrong, but with code I show in first block that will freeze first app (with button) till reader finish read?

Comment: May be it is how you perform the printing in PrintRecipt project.

Comment: Loading 100 K rows could take 2 seconds indeed.

Comment: Well, let say that, I'm doing something that take 10 second in additional project. So running it as Process will freeze main app for this 10 second?

Comment: I don't really know but I think this depends on the resources shared between the two threads - Again, I am not sure about this. This is a fair question that you may want to highlight in bold in the body of your question.